# Does mt_rand() generate same number twice?

Tags: php, random, mersenne-twister

I am trying to generate unique token id, can i use `mt_rand()`?

will `mt_rand()` generate same number twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mt_rand` will generate the same number twice, yes. Every random number generator will *probably* do so eventually. (Theoretically) every number has the same chance of being generated every time the generator is run. It *could* randomly generate the same number many times in a row. It's random.

To use a random number generator for unique ids, the *probability* of generating the same number twice must be so low as to be irrelevant in practice. In this regard, `mt_rand` is probably not sufficient. The concept of randomly generated unique ids has been formalised into [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), which you should use for exactly the purpose of a *universally unique id*.

Take [this quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates):

> ...only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%.

Since `mt_rand` returns a 32-bit integer on 32-bit systems, it can only return 2^32 unique values, which is a mere 4,294,967,296 unique values. If you were generating a billion `mt_rand` values every second, you're basically *guaranteed* a duplicate after 4 seconds. That hopefully illustrates the difference of scale between UUIDs and `mt_rand` and why that matters. Even if you're generating much fewer than 1 billion ids every second, you'll still need to choose an algorithm which makes collisions practically impossible, not just unlikely.

Comment: ...and for PHP, there is a perfectly good function that does just that: http://php.net/uniqid

Comment: @Omkar `uniqid` is ***not*** a UUID implementation! It's not very good!

Comment: @JeroenvandenBroek Sorry, nope.

Comment: @deceze what will be better to generate a unique id?

Comment: @deceze How is it any different from using `mt_rand()`?

Comment: @O-mkar I'm pretty sure you'll have to use a PECL package or other 3rd party library. I know there's a PECL package for UUIDs.

Comment: @Chuck 1) UUIDs have a much larger range of 2^128 bits, whereas `mt_rand` uses at most 2^64 on 64bit systems (and I'm not even sure it actually does that, so it's usually 2^32). That makes collisions much less likely. 2) `mt_rand` is seeded by the current time, so running it in parallel at exactly the same time will return the same value. UUIDs are designed specifically to prevent that.

Comment: @deceze I see. It all depends of whether O-mkar needs an actual UUID or not. If he doesn't (and it sounds like he doesn't from his question), and is happy just using mt_rand(), I don't see why uniqid wouldn't work better. If he really needs a proper UUID then PECL or another 3rd party library would be better.

Comment: uniqid _does_ provide a unique ID. You're right that it's not universally unique, but @Omkar doesn't seem to need that. I should have elaborated in my message, but `uniqid` is fine in this particular situation.

Comment: @Jeroen Do we actually know what exactly the OP's situation is? FWIW, `uniqid` is basically just a wrapper around `microtime`. It does have issues with parallel execution. As I wrote, for *limited* scenarios `mt_rand` will probably be *good enough*. But since we don't know the specifics of the situation, *in general* I cannot recommend either `uniqid` or `mt_rand`. Also, a solution which comes with a number of asterisks and caveats and *ifs* and *whens* is probably not worth using when there's a great alternative available.

Comment: I find it really tricky that this answer is the accepted answer, despite all its enormous inaccuracies. The first word is emphasized and hopelessly wrong - the whole point of a random generator is that it *may* return the same number twice in a row, it's just highly unlikely. It's not just not a good enough generator to *guarantee* uniqueness, it practically guarantees its absence - which is, again, the whole point of a random number generator. It's an XY answer fixing the underlying problem correctly, but with too many factual inaccuracies for my liking.

Comment: @Niels Point taken. This really wasn't a terribly good explanation regarding RNGs, it was more focussed on the OPs problem at hand. Revised.

Answer (score 17):

This is the first time ever I'm going to answer a question [with just a comic](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator), just because it's the right answer:

[image]

[The original on Dilbert.com](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/).

Answer (score 0):

`mt_rand()` will return a random number on each call.

But eventually, it will return numbers that have already been returned to you. That is because, along with being consistent with desired statistical properties of randomness, the generator has a finite (although for Mersenne Twister, a very large) *periodicity*. If this behaviour is undesirable then your best bet is to shuffle a unique set using that generator.

Answer (score 0):

[`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) has the following caveats:

> **Caution**: This function does not generate cryptographically secure
> values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need
> a cryptographically secure value, consider using
> openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

And

> **Caution**: The distribution of mt_rand() return values is biased towards
> even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32.

If you're fine with it not being completely unbiased, you should be ok.

But, if that's the case, why aren't you using [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid)?